# Understanding complex multiplication as vector addition

Tags: vector-spaces, complex-numbers

I've been studying complex multiplication and vector math lately. Below is a visual representation of what happens when one multiplies a complex number $ 1 + xi $ by itself repeatedly, plotting the result of each multiplication in the complex plane:

[image: Complex multiplication]

Looking at this, I thought to myself, "What if $1 + xi$ were thought of like a vector, something like $<1,\ x>$?"

Then A--the length of the hypotenuse of the initial triangle, now thought of as a vector--would be $<1,\ x>$

What would the vector from A to AxA be?

I didn't have very good intuition for this. So, I defined an abstract vector $<a,b>$ Because the distance from A to AxA is x, I defined the length of this vector as $\sqrt{a^2\ +\ b^2}\ =\ |<a,b>|$ Then, I gave it a name: [$\vec{Snarf}$](http://statici.behindthevoiceactors.com/behindthevoiceactors/_img/chars/char_5576.jpg). For lack of a better word.

Literally.

$\vec{Snarf}$ is orthogonal to A, so $A\cdot\vec{Snarf}\ =\ 0$ Therefore, $<1,x>\cdot<a,b>\ =\ 0$ and $a\ +\ bx\ =\ 0$

Also, $\vec{Snarf}$ is just x rotated a little bit. So, $|<a,b>|\ =\ x\ =\ \sqrt{a^2\ +\ b^2}$

Next, we have the following statement from the original complex multiplication:

$
AxA\ =\ (\ 1\ +\ xi\ )^2 \\
AxA\ =\ (\ 1\ +\ xi\ )(\ 1\ +\ xi\ ) \\
AxA\ =\ 1\ +\ 2xi\ +\ x^2i \\
AxA\ =\ 1\ +\ 2xi\ -\ x^2 \\
AxA\ =\ (\ 1\ -\ x^2\ )\ +\ 2xi \\
AxA\ =\ <1-x^2,\ 2x> \\
$

Combining this result with our definitions of A and $\vec{Snarf}$:

$
\begin{align}
A\ +\ \vec{Snarf}\ &=\ AxA \\
<1,\ x>\ +\ <a,b>\ &=\ <1-x^2,\ 2x> \\
<1\ +\ a,\ x\ +\ b>\ &=\ <1-x^2,\ 2x> \\
1\ +\ a\ &=\ 1\ -\ x^2 \\
x\ +\ b\ &=\ 2x
\end{align}
$

So, now we have three unknowns--a, b, and x--and four equations:

$\begin{align}
a\ +\ bx\ &=\ 0 \\
\sqrt{a^2\ +\ b^2}\ &=\ x \\
1\ +\ a\ &=\ 1\ -\ x^2 \\
x\ +\ b\ &=\ 2x
\end{align}$

We're in good shape!

However,

$
\begin{align}
x\ +\ b\ &=\ 2x \\
b\ &=\ x \\
\end{align}
$

Substituting this into $\sqrt{a^2\ +\ b^2}\ =\ x$ gives $\sqrt{a^2\ +\ b^2}\ =\ b$, which can only be true if $a\ =\ 0$

$\begin{align}
\sqrt{0\ +\ b^2}\ &=\ b \\
\sqrt{b^2}\ &=\ b \\
b\ &=\ b \\
\end{align}$

So, if we think of things in the complex plane as vectors and think of the vector from A to AxA as $<a,b>$, we end up with $<0,0>\ =\ \vec{Snarf}$

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: The distance from $A$ to $A^2$ is $|A(A-1)| = x\sqrt{1+x^2}$. And there is no reason that $(A^2 - A)$ should be orthogonal to $A$.

Comment: If you think of complex numbers as ordered pairs of reals (which is indeed the rigorous definition), their multiplication is a rule: $(a,b)(c,d) = (ac-bd,ad+bc)$. This is exactly what defers the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}^2$.